# Modifying Default Contact Forms (Individual, Household & Organization)

Tags: contacts

How can I modify the default contact forms and remove the unnecessary fields and add new fields instead.

Comment: Please specify whether you are referring to Civi contact forms or CMS contact forms and which versions you are using

Comment: What would be the difference between Civi Contact Forms or CMS Contact forms? I think I am referring to CiviCRM Contact Forms.

Comment: OK - glad we're on the same page now and we understand we are talking about profiles - please submit a screenshot of what you when navigate to the reserved profiles tab as Pete instructed you to do - you should see Edit hyperlinks to the right-hand side of each field as well as an Add Field button.

Comment: I think there's still some confusion as to what the question is about - I'm going to include screenshots on both Pete's answer and mine to make it clearer to them which answer refers to which screen.

Comment: pls including Links and Screenshots to help clarify what you are asking for

Comment: To answer your question regarding the difference between Civi Contact Forms and CMS contact forms, this thread with valuable input from Jon will give you a precise answer: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26500/how-to-display-custom-fields-2-fields-in-row-instead-of-new-line-for-each-field

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the contact screens that look like this:
[image]
You can add custom fields as per [the documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/).

To remove/rearrange fields, install the [Contact Layout Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) extension.  Note that this extension requires the very latest version of CiviCRM (5.5+).

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the "New Individual" etc. form that looks like this:
[image]
You can remove some of the fields from **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Display Preferences.  You can't remove all the fields from this screen without coding a custom extension.

You can add fields by creating custom fields.  See [the documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/) for more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the "New Individual" etc. pop-ups that look like this:
[image]

Then at /civicrm/admin/uf/group?reset=1 you should see a tab for Reserved Profiles

You should see the New Individual one there and should be able to add other Fields to that profile

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I went there, I did see New Individual, when I click on Fields, I only see 3 fields First Name, Last Name and E-mail, I don't see any other fields that I can edit or remove.

Comment: what is an example of a field you want to 'remove' - per Jon's comment your Question is interpretable in various ways - it will save everyone's time if you including both links and screenshots